# how to create information window in google map in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am making a rails application. And I am supposed to show the pin point on the **google map** with pin point according the location. For that particular location, I have **some details**, so what I want is, as soon as I click on any **pin point**, I should get all the details which I inserted in my database for that particular location.

Can any one please help me by providing your known information or provide any **API link** regarding that?

Comment: good.......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found this answer.

I have gone through the `gmap4rails` wiki document, then I got a method as below:

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  "Enter your required content"
end
```

Now I am able to show the details of that particular location on its respective pin point.